Measure dependance of groupoid von Neumann algebra
Let $(G,\mu)$ be a measured groupoid and denote by $\nu,\nu^{-1}$ the measures on all of $G$ induced by $\mu$ and Haar system $\{\lambda^x\}$.
I have a question regarding the dependance of the groupoid von Neumann algebra $\text{vN}_\mu(G)$ on $\mu$.
In the above setting, we can consider the space $L^2(G,\nu^{-1})$ and the left regular representation $\lambda_\mu: C_c(G) \rightarrow B(L^2(G,\nu^{-1})$ given by $\lambda(f)g = f*g$. By completing $C_c(G)$ w.r.t the norm $\|f\|_{r,\mu} := \|\lambda(f)\|$ we obtain a $C^*$-algebra denoted by $C_{r,\mu}^*(G)$ and by taking the double commutant we get the von Neumann algebra $\text{vN}_\mu(G) := C_{r,\mu}^*(G)'' \subseteq B(L^2(G,\nu^{-1}))$.
It can be seen that the $C^*$-algebra $C_{r,\mu}^*(G)$ does only depend on the support of $\mu$ [1, Proposition 3.1.2], however I do not know if the same holds for the von Neumann algebras since the space $B(L^2(G,\nu^{-1}))$ can vary a lot depending on $\mu$.

If $\mu_1, \mu_2 $ are two quasi-invariant measures on $G^0$ with the same support, is it true that $ \text{vN}_{\mu_1}(G) \cong \text{vN}_{\mu_2}(G) $?

Of course, if $\mu_1, \mu_2 $ are equivalent the above is true.

[1] Paterson, Alan L. T., Groupoids, inverse semigroups, and their operator algebras, Progress in Mathematics (Boston, Mass.). 170. Boston, MA: Birkhäuser. xvi, 274 p. (1999). ZBL0913.22001.

What do you mean by the support of $\mu$ if $G$ is a measured groupoid?

A measured groupoid is a pair $(G,\mu)$ where $G$ is a locally compact groupoid (+ a Haar system) and $\mu$ a measure on the unit space $G^0$ that satisfies an invariance condition called quasi-invariance. The support of $\mu$ is the usual measure theoretic notion, i.e. the largest (closed) subset of $G^0$ for which every open neighbourhood of every point of the set has positive measure.

This is not the usual definition. A measured groupoid is not a topological one additionally endowed with a quasi-invariant measure. Its standard definition doesn't involve any topology.

No, the von Neumann algebra can vary a lot, even when the groupoid is a transformation groupoid for an action of a discrete group $\Gamma$ on a compact space $X$. For instance, take $X$ to be the Cantor set $(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$ and let $\Gamma$ be the direct sum $\Gamma = (\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})^{(\mathbb{N})}$ acting by translation. Whenever $\mu_n$ is a sequence of probability measures on the two-point set $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$ with $p_n = \mu_n(0)$ satisfying $0 < p_n < 1$, the product measure $\mu = \prod_n \mu_n$ is quasi-invariant. The resulting crossed product von Neumann algebra is an infinite tensor product of $2 \times 2$ matrices w.r.t. a sequence of states given by the eigenvalues $p_n$, $1-p_n$. If for instance you take $0 < \lambda < 1$ and $p_n = (1+\lambda)^{-1}$, you get the Powers factors of type III$_\lambda$, which are all nonisomorphic.

What a neat example, thank you! Just to make sure I followed, if we pick different $\lambda$'s we obtain different probability measures, all of which give non-zero measure to points, meaning the support is always the whole Cantor set, correct?

Most of the time, in particular when all $p_n$ are equal, the measure $\mu$ is nonatomic. But the support is indeed the entire Cantor set. If $U \subset (\mathbb{Z}/Z\mathbb{Z})^{\mathbb{N}}$ is an open subset, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1,\ldots,x_n \in \mathbb{Z}/Z\mathbb{Z}$ such that ${x_1} \times \cdots \times {x_n} \times (\mathbb{Z}/Z\mathbb{Z})^{[n+1,\infty)}$ is a subset of $U$, with strictly positive measure $\mu_1(x_1) \cdots \mu_n(x_n)$.
